# How to deal with double colon (::) and pipe (%>%) notation in R?

Tags: r, pipe, r-package

I am developing an R Package following the guidelines from http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html which says that it is better to use `package::function()` instead of using `library(package)` because loading the package would change the R landscape. However, the code I am using for the package uses the pipe operator `%>%` from the package `magrittr` and when I try to run it without loding `magrittr` it gives me the following error:

```
Error in scores %>% dplyr::group_by(group)  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
```

I have tried to use `magrittr::%>%`, but it did not work. I have also tried parenthesizing `(dplyr::group_by(group))`, but I still got the same error.

Is there a way to fix this or should I remove pipes and use the nested option?

Thank you!

Comment: `magrittr:\`%>%\`` will give you the pipe, as will `dplyr::\`%>%\`` (which is just a re-export from `magrittr`). Because the `%`-functions are "specials" in R parlance, you need to use backticks around the function name itself.

Comment: You can also run `usethis::use_pipe()` in the console. The package `usethis` will add what you need to import the pipe to your NAMESPACE, and then you can just use as is in the package. That is what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try evaluating the pipe infix operator as a standard function

```
dplyr::`%>%`(scores, dplyr::by_group(group))
```

Alternatively, you can set an exported pipe function to a different variable and subsequently evaluate it as a binary operator

```
`%pipe%` <- dplyr::`%>%`

scores %pipe% dplyr::group_by(group)
```